# Searching a nxn matrix

Tags: search, time, matrix, complexity-theory

I just wanted to confirm my answers and see if there was a faster way.

If there was a nxn matrix that was sorted, what is the best way to search it and what is its complexity?
- Binary search the rows, then binary search the columns. O(logN).

If there was a nxn matrix with sorted rows and unsorted columns, what is the best way to search it and what is its complexity?
- Binary search the rows, then linear search the columns. O(N).

Comment: Just curious if anyone had a clue. Is this that tough of a question?

Answer (score 1):

Define what sorted means over a matrix and define what you want to search. Perhaps add an example.

To make it more clear, is this sorted (1):

```
1 6
4 5
```

Or is this sorted (2):

```
1 4
5 6
```

And, what do you mean with search. Do you want to find a single value in the whole matrix(a), a single value in every row(b), or a different value in every row (c)?

---

For (1)(a) it is n*log(n) (n searches, one for every row)

For (2)(a) it is log(n) (view it as one big row, so log(n*n) => log(n^2) => 2*log(n) => log(n)

---

For (1)(b) it is n*log(n) (n searches, one for every row)

For (2)(b) it is log(n)

---

For (1)(c) it is n*log(n) (n searches, one for every row)

For (2)(c) it is at least n*log(n), but probably you could sort the values and use the presorted matrix to get it done in log(n) or log(n)*log(n), this needs further analysis

---

Everything without a prove, just based on some basic thoughts.